# Find $x$ and $y$ by Cramer from $\left\{\begin{aligned} \frac{2x+2}{2y-3}&=\frac{x-2}{y+3}\\ \frac{x+2}{3y-2}&=\frac{x-1}{3y+8} \end{aligned}\right.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Find $x$ and $y$ with Cramer rule from these equations
>   $$\left\{
> \begin{aligned} 
> \frac{2x+2}{2y-3}&=\frac{x-2}{y+3} \\
> \frac{x+2}{3y-2}&=\frac{x-1}{3y+8}
> \end{aligned} 
> \right.
> $$

I'm getting stuck to make the $x$ and $y$ out for making system equation matrix. Any idea?

Comment: Multiplying both sides by least common denominators and canceling similar terms will eliminate the nonlinear terms.

Comment: @KittyL It's getting complicated when multiplying the numerator afterward.

Comment: It's really not that complicated. I will show you an example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show you the first one:

$$\frac{2x+2}{2y-3}=\frac{x-2}{y+3} \implies\\
(2x+2)(y+3)=(x-2)(2y-3)\implies\\
2xy+6x+2y+6=2xy-3x-4y+6$$

Can you see how you can cancel and combine the terms now?

Comment: @làntèrn: The $2xy$ on both sides cancel with each other. Since you are doing Cramer's rule, I'm sure you should have learnt how to write a system of linear equations in its matrix form?